# Android inflater for ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I’m using an inflater for a `LinerLayout`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_overlay,
            null, false);
```

It's working fine. But when the user rotates the screen, the system is using another layout xml file from the `layout-land` folder which has the same RelativeLayout, but inside a ScrollView. So how can I manage the code so that it can be the same for both the xml files?

```
 private void addOverlayView(boolean initLayout)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View temp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coupon, null);
    mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) temp.findViewById(R.id.testlayoutnew);
    mUILayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (initLayout)
    {
        mUILayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    addContentView(mUILayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    mInstructionsView = mUILayout.findViewById(R.id.instructions);
    mInstructionsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mUILayout.bringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Don't assign the inflated layout directly to `mUILayout`, instead give a distinct id to the `Relativelayout` and look for it in the inflated layout. Also, please don't prefix your questions titles with Android, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Comment: mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.id.testcpn, null, false);---------is that going o work?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? `mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) (inflater.inflate(R.id.testcpn, null).findViewById(R.id.the_id_assigned_to_the_relativelayout));`

Comment: have used this:  mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.id.the_id_assigned_to_the_relativelayout, null);


error is:
09-03 18:25:15.193: E/AndroidRuntime(944): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b000b type #0x12 is not valid
09-03 18:25:15.193: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)

Comment: The idea was to first inflate the layout and then look for the `RelativeLayout` and not use the `LayoutInflater` with that id: `View temp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_overlay, null); mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) temp.findViewById(R.id.the_id_assigned_to_the_relativelayout);`. Assig the id n both layouts.

Comment: i've put the same id in both the xml. Its fine in the horizontal. When done potrait its showing this error:

09-03 18:35:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):  at com.example.testact.CouponActivity.addOverlayView(CouponActivity.java:254)
09-03 18:38:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-03 18:38:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
09-03 18:38:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):  at

Comment: I hope you aren't adding the `mUILayout` to another layout. You'll need to add the temporary view temp instead.

Comment: Full method pasted. I'm calling addOverlayView method for both horizontal and portrait screen. Both the xmls have this

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/testlayoutnew"..